# How can i remove filter data in pandas (Data Munging)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

Data with me in pandas series:

```
data = ["1. stock1 (1991)",  
"3. stock13 (1993)",  
"5. stock19 (1999)",  
"89. stock105 (2001)"] # pandas Series
```

I need to filter each string and saved as

```
s.no    sdata       year  
1       stock1      1991  
3       stock13     1993  
5       stock19     1999  
89      stock105    2001
```

I have tried using

```
data = stock["Rank & Title"].str.split(".")
```

Comment: You may want to add a flag for Regex (Regular Expressions) on your question.

Comment: This seems to be a more regex problem than pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can try `str.extract` method with *regex*:

```
data = ["1. stock1 (1991)",  
"3. stock13 (1993)",  
"5. stock19 (1999)",  
"89. stock105 (2001)"]

s = pd.Series(data)

s.str.extract("(?P<sno>\d+)\.\s(?P<sdata>\w+)\s\((?P<year>\d+)\)", expand=True)

# sno      sdata    year
#0  1     stock1    1991
#1  3    stock13    1993
#2  5    stock19    1999
#3  89  stock105    2001
```

Breaks down on the *regex*, `(?P<sno>\d+)\.\s(?P<sdata>\w+)\s\((?P<year>\d+)\)` can be simplified to `(\d+)\.\s(\w+)\s\((\d+)\)` without naming the captured groups (which is done with `?P<name>`); `(\d+)`, `(\w+)` and `(\d+)` captures the *s.no*, *stockname* and *year* respectively.

---

Or you may just want to split on white space and then clean columns up depending on how your real data looks like:

```
(s.str.split(" ", expand=True)
  # strip period and parenthesis
 .apply(lambda col: col.str.strip(".()"))
  # rename columns
 .rename(columns={0: "s.no", 1: "sdata", 2: "year"}))

# s.no     sdata    year
#0   1    stock1    1991
#1   3   stock13    1993
#2   5   stock19    1999
#3  89  stock105    2001
```